# Sending and SMS from your computer

Tags: sms

There is a ton of data on this subject where you simply take the phone-number+@mobile-carrier.com and send a message, that is not what I am looking to do.

I want to send an SMS, from the command line, in this case, using php, but I would be happy to use bash, and will probably make it into an app or plug in for Safari eventually.  Right now, a test case would suit me fine.

I would like to do something like this:
./sms 619-555-1212 "this is the message"

I don't need to receive the message back to the computer, this is a sending only agent.

The criteria that makes all the data I find on this not work, is that I want my correct from: number to show up.  I have tried using the email gateway method and changing he from: headers, but it appears they are stripped at the gateway.

I don't mind paying a service to give me certain amount of SMS credits to make this happen.  I want to avoid any hardware, where I would have to get a modem or otherwise to connect to my computer.

If I do use a service, something with an example of how to do so within their API would greatly appreciated.  I feel this should take me no more than 15 minutes, but I am hours into research and not getting very far with all the little scripts out there that do nothing close to what I want to do.

Thank you very much and sorry that I don't understand this protocol to the best of my ability.

Answer (score 1):

You can send with Twilio using cURL very easily since sending SMS is a simple POST request with three parameters. Here's an example of a bash script that makes calls but could be modified to use the SMS API instead. http://labs.twilio.com/bash/

(I work at Twilio)

Answer (score 0):

you will need sms gateway like http://www.clickatell.com/ for that

Comment: Worst system I have ever used, stay away from them like the plague.  If you don't write down every key and code they give you, you have to email them and tell them your business plan on what you plan on doing before they will give it to you.  I also created 5 total accounts with the same username and password, and was given 10 free credits on each account, but since they are all the same account, I have 4 accounts with 10 credits, and one with 50 credits. I have no faith in this system.

Answer (score 0):

You can use any gateway that charges you a few cents for every message sent. They have a simple REST API which requires a very little coding. They even provide you a sample example to get started.

Comment: Who is they, any recommendations?

Comment: Why don't u try http://www.smsglobal.com Their api can be accessed at http://www.smsglobal.com/en-au/technology/developers.php with example codes as well. Hope that helps.